# An Error about Nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am a beginner for Nodejs,I study this follow by the guide.
Now,I have a `module.js`

```
function Hello()
{
  var name;
  this.setName=function(thyName){
      name=thyName;
  };

  this.sayHello=function()
  {
    console.log("hello,"+name);
  };
};

module.exports=Hello;
```

and `getModule.js`

```
var hello = require("./module");
hello.setName("HXH");
hello.sayHello();
```

But when I run :

```
d:\nodejs\demo>node getModule.js
```

I got the Error:

```
d:\nodejs\demo\getModule.js:2
hello.setName("HXH");
      ^
TypeError: Object function Hello()
{
  var name;
  this.setName=function(thyName){
      name=thyName;
  };

  this.sayHello=function()
  {
    console.log("hello,"+name);
  };
} has no method 'setName'
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\nodejs\demo\getModule.js:2:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Why I got this?I just follow the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what guide you're following, but `module.js` exports a class. Since `module.js` exports a class, when you do `require('./module')`, you get a class. However, you're using that class you got as if it were an instance of the class. If you want an instance, you need to use `new` like so:

```
var Hello = require('./module');  // Hello is the class
var hello = new Hello();  // hello is an instance of the class Hello
hello.setName("HXH");
hello.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, NodeJS follow [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) spec for module implementation. You should know how does it work.

Secondly, if you want to use module like the way you write, you should modify your `module.js` and `getModule.js` as following:

```
//module.js
module.exports.Hello= Hello;

//getModule.js.js
var Hello = require("./module");
var hello = new Hello();
hello.setName("HXH");
hello.sayHello();
```